# Searching for a raw string (r'\n') within a raw string full of ('\n') resulting in an empty result set

Tags: python, regex

```
import re
re.search(r'\n',  r'\n\n')
```

Is resulting in an empty result-set. Should this pull the raw string '\n'?

Thanks

Comment: A string `r'\n'` contains 2 chars, a backslash and `n`, while `r'\n'` regex matches a newline.

Comment: However, I converted both the pattern and string to raw strings.  Shouldn't that mean the regex is trying to match two characters, which is within the string?

Comment: `r'\n'`  and `'\n'` regex patterns both match a  newline.

Comment: I see - that's super confusing.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: The string contains a backslash and an n, but `re.search` doesn't mean "search for this string". "Search for this string" is just `str.find`.